# Blackberry res folder naming convention

Tags: blackberry, naming-conventions

I created a static function like this.

```java
public static Bitmap Bitmap(String path) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap
            .getBitmapResource(Display.getWidth() + "/" + path);
    System.out.println(Display.getWidth() + "" + path);
    return bitmap;
}
```

However, when I called like this,

```java
private Bitmap download = Config_GlobalFunction.Bitmap("btn_download.png");
```

The output gave me `FRIDG could not find 320/btn_download.png`.

In my `res` folder, I got an folder which was `img` and inside `img` got 6 different folders which were `160`, `240`, `320`, `360`, `480` and `640` folder.

How can I call correct folder's image based on `Display.getWidth()`?

Comment: why ur using Display.getWidth()?

Comment: @RajKamal, he has a good idea.  He wants to have different versions of some of his images, that are drawn to look best at different resolutions.  So, he might have a different version of a toolbar image for 360 pixel wide screens, and another for 480 pixel wide screens.  Android has a very similar mechanism in place, and iPhone at least has a dual resolution system (e.g. icon.png and icon@2x.png).

Comment: @Alan lai r u taking same image of different resolutions into the project?

Comment: image same but difference size that why I need got different folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It **is** possible to have a folder hierarchy under the `/res` folder but you must use `getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)` rather than `Bitmap.getBitmapResource()` in order to create your resource.

This example creates a Bitmap from the path `/res/img/hi_res/ui/action_arrow.png`:

```
String imagePath = "/img/hi_res/ui/action_arrow.png"; 
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(imagePath);
byte[] imageBytes = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmapFromBytes(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length, 1);
```

It's a bit more work but it does mean you can have a nice folder structure, rather than hundreds of images lumped together in a single folder.

Comment: +1.  This is great to know.  I've used `getResourceAsStream()` for non image assets before, and never made the connection to write a helper to use it to get Bitmaps.  I think the allure of the `Bitmap.getBitmapResource()` method was too easy to pass up :)

Comment: @AlanLai That's 2 questions :) 1. Yes 2. I don't think so but feel free to try the Eclipse memory profiler and report back.

Answer (score 2):

I've had problems with this before.  [BlackBerry apps don't seem to be well setup to handle resource files in subfolders.](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Help-me-Resource-file-path-problem-in-JDE-4-5/td-p/297942)  That is, you can store your resources in folders, but when bundled into your app (.cod file), they will essentially all be dumped into the same folder.

As you can see, that causes problems if you have multiple resources with the same name (but in different folders).

I used to use the Netbeans IDE to build BlackBerry apps, and with the Netbeans BlackBerry plugin, it seemed to handle this.  But, with the RIM JDE, or Eclipse plugin, it doesn't.  Perhaps it's something in the `ant` build script behind the toolset?

Anyway, I know you would like to do something similar to Android, where you would have:

- **res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png**
- **res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png**
- **res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png**

and pick the correct version of icon.png based on screen size / resolution.  That's a good idea.

However, for simplicity, I would probably recommend changing your system to just use **prefixes** on your resource names, instead of folders.  It's a pain, I know, but BlackBerry seems to handle it better.

So, just call your images:

- **res/img/320_btn_download.png**
- **res/img/360_btn_download.png**
- **res/img/480_btn_download.png**

and then your code can be:

```java
public static Bitmap Bitmap(String path) {
    return Bitmap.getBitmapResource(Display.getWidth() + "_" + path);
}
```

Comment: you mean no need difference folder but need to change the image name? and put inside `img` folder

Comment: @AlanLai, That's right.  I think you **can** put the images in folders if you like, but when the app builds, they will all be combined into one *virtual* folder.  So, keeping images in different folders might help you stay organized on your computer, but it also might allow you to name two files in different folders with the same name ... which won't work for your app, and might be easy to miss.  So, if you don't have too many images, it might be safest just to keep them all in the `img/` folder.  Note: remember to **Upvote** answers :)

Comment: seriously, i got 370 images now =(

Comment: @AlanLai, yeah it's not fun to manage huge directories of files.  Like I said, if you want, you **can** keep them in folders.  But, when the app builds, you will lose that.  All images will be in the same *folder*, and if any are named the same, the app won't work correctly.  So, if you do, for example, keep `res/img/360/360_button.png` and `res/img/320/320_button.png`, you just need to remember to always give images unique names (for example, begin with the pixel width).  If you keep all images in the same folder on your computer, the OS will force names to be unique, and you can't forget.

Comment: @AlanLai, by the way, although I think the information I posted is good to be aware of, and still applies to `Bitmap.getBitmapResource()`, I think donturner's solution will work better for you.  You just have to write 5 or 10 lines of code once, and then use it whenever you want to load `Bitmap` objects.  Feel free to Unaccept this answer, and Accept Don's :)

Answer (score 1):

if u want to get images depending on their resolutions then...give names to the images  according to its resolution like `320x240_img1`, `360x480_img1`. no need to place these images in different folders....dump these images in ur res folder and call like this

```java
int x = Display.getWidth();
int y = Display.getHeight();

String xx = Integer.toString(x);
String yy =Integer.toString(y);
_encImg = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource(xx+"x"+yy+".jpg");
```