# BlackBerry App for different BlackBerry devices - Design Suggestion

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I am writing an app and willing to package it for different BlackBerry devices with different properties/features and resolutions.
**My problem is how do I go about creating a `DeviceConfigurationManager` that will give me device specific properties/paddings/margins/resolutions etc?** 
I have read here on SO about using `Ui.UNITS_pt` for fonts, having multiple images for different resolution devices and other things that has helped me in designing my `DeviceConfigurationManager` . 
For example in my buttons I have used margins and so for various devices I kept one device as a reference and relatively returned margins for other devices on width(`Display.getWidth()>320`) check. But I have seen I still  don't get exact perfection for other devices (Buttons set centered for the base device doesn't also get perfectly centered for other devices). 
Please suggest some other or a better way about designing my `DeviceConfigurationManager` class. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would check out [Don's answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11551148/119114).  It discusses how to organize, and dynamically load, image resources that are sized for different BlackBerry screen sizes.  Similar to what's built in to Android, with drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Can't offer too much help - but plenty of sympathy. If you're developing for the BlackBerry Java OS you're just going to have to get used to having lots of boiler-plate to handle the different devices. I suspect you do the same as me; have a class that runs on startup, reads the screen size and then sets all kinds of static params for font sizes, padding etc etc.

Comment: Thanks Jon! It really is sympathetic on BlackBerry's part :P