# Handling Touch EventListener in presence of navigationClick()

Tags: blackberry, drop-down-menu, tabs

In application, Whenever i move bewteen tabs a full menu, copy, switch application pop up open. 
[image: Here is screen shot when i navigate between tabs. This popup opens.]

To prevent this i override navigationClick method.
   Now pop is not shown. In my second tab i have implemented drop down list. Because i have override navigationClick method when i click on drop down list it is not showing me list of items.
Any idea will be apperciated.

**Update:**

Here is navigationClick implementation:

```
public boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) { 
  return true; 
}
```

Comment: what did you use to implement tabs - buttons?

Comment: please show your navigationClick() implementation

Comment: Better to provide code snippet here. If you think the you write navigationclick corrrect, to stop un-Popup the Menu option use this "public boolean onMenu(int instance) 
 {
  return true;
 }" . and try that.

Comment: @Eugen Martynov: I hve used Label for tabs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909931/tabs-in-blackberry

Comment: @Nate:- Thanks. Here is navigationClick implementation.             public            boolean  navigationClick(int status, int time)
 {
  return true;
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by implementing navigationClick() while creating lablelField

```
tab5 = new LabelField("News", LabelField.FOCUSABLE | LabelField.HIGHLIGHT_SELECT)
{
        public boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
        {
            return true;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure while selecting a tab, no errors occur which probably could be the reason for the menu options to pop up. if this is fixed i guess the subsequent problem will be dissolved!

Out of my experience i have observed the menu pops up in blackberry when a NullPointerException event occurs.

Just check the logs or debug to make sure no exception occurs when you navigate between tabs

Comment: Thanks for rply bt i am not getting any exception while moving between tabs.

Comment: Can you please post your code so that i can have a look and try it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click the labelfield then:

```
LabelField labelField=new LabelField("Click")
{
     protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) 
     {
         doLabelFieldClicked();
         return true;
     }
}
```

and if Menu option is highlighted then override this:

```
public boolean onMenu(int instance) 
{ 
    return true; //It doesn't show the Menu option.
}
```

If I am thinking wrong let me know.