# Blackberry app for different blackberry devices

Tags: blackberry, screen-resolution

First of all, I'm not a Blackberry user. I have made a blackberry application for 7.0+ OS Versions. From the start I tested the app on Blackberry 9900 Bold Simulator and same device (Same device provided by the company). So didn't really check the application in other blackberry device. But now I am given another resolution BB device and all the GUI stuff is disturbed.

What should I do now?

One way is that I should check the resolution and `Display.getHorizontalResolution()` and `Display.getVerticalResolution()` and make GUI's accordingly but since I have 20+ screens I won't be doing this.

If you have any generic solution please provide.

Comment: The proper solution depends on what kind of GUI you have.  Depending on what's inside your GUI, you may want a completely different layout for different devices/screens, or just to make small adjustments to the position of your fields.  Depending on what's inside the layout, it may be better to use built-in managers with proper field margins, or it may be better to create a custom manager that places fields at specific locations, in `sublayout()`.  It's hard to give you a good answer without knowing what the UI looks like.

Comment: @Nate http://www.coroflot.com/ashahwaiz-mobilezapp/Kenexa These are the application pictures. I have used Vertical and Horizontal Field Managers mostly and to set some button positions have used button.setMargin(x,x,x,x). So keeping in view what is the solution?

Comment: You can also [take a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11551148/119114).  It only really deals with adding **images** to your app to support different screens.  But, it might give you good ideas for how to handle other device-specific details of your UI, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use [embedded Eclipse plugin preprocessor](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21065/Specifying_preprocessor_directives_657636_11.jsp) or [Antenna preprocessor](http://antenna.sourceforge.net/wtkpreprocess.php) for conditional compilation with [BlackBerry Ant Tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/) to generate different application files for different target OS-es, and/or different target devices.

Consider [Alx-task](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs#alx) to generate alx (application descriptor file) that supports different platforms/OS-es.

Also check [this article](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Create-a-single-alx-file-to-install-multiple-versions-of-an/ta-p/445156). It will help with your task.

Comment: But how I'm going to set the GUI's for other devices? I'm sorry but really couldn't followed you. It must support all devices of 7.0+ BB OS. Within that it has many resolution devices.How im going to be perfect on those devices with this GUI?

Comment: There are two ways. The first - add the biggest possible images to your project and then scale down them proporionally according to the actual device display capabilities. Scaling down does not significantly affect on the image quality. To get device display capabilities look at `net.rim.device.api.system.Display` class and its methods. The second way - separate image resources for the every device resolution to different folders. And use Apache Ant to build different cod-files for different device types. I would prefer the first way.