# Blackberry 6,7 UI Design

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

How can we design UIs for blackberry OS 6 and 7?  Is **coding** the only available option? Are there any other tools available ?

I have to design for different screen sizes, so how do I handle the arrangement of components in the screen?

Comment: You can develop an HTML5 Webworks app, so theoretically you could use tools to generate HTML5 markup. For a Java application you need to code.

Comment: Thanks for your responseI need to develop an apps which supports in both platforms blackberry 6,7 . So for creating the UI coding is the only option you are saying ?

Comment: you can use if else loop for tis. if(width=360 and height=480)then set fields . else if 480 - 800 then arrange fields and so on.

Comment: If you're familiar with Android, and how it loads resources for different screen sizes, you might [take a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11551148/119114), which suggests a similar way to handle image loading for BlackBerry Java apps.